# (Linux-Ubunto Permission problem) Nginx can't load static/media files from Django Site

Tags: python, django, linux, nginx, permissions

this is more of linux permission problem. Im trying to create a website with nginx and django, but I'm getting error `403 forbidden`, so my nginx is not able to read my statics files, I'm not experienced with linux(Ubunto)

```
failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

I will show you my file permissions:

```
 ls -ld /home/jamelaumn/myproject
drwxr-xr-x 11 www-data www-data 4096 Jul  9 23:25 /home/jamelaumn/myproject

ls -ld /home/jamelaumn/myproject/deploystatic
drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Jul  9 23:22 /home/jamelaumn/myproject/deploystatic


ls -ld /home/jamelaumn/myproject/media
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Jul  9 23:25 /home/jamelaumn/myproject/media

ls -ld /home/jamelaumn/myproject/media/product_images
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Jul  9 23:25 /home/jamelaumn/myproject/media/product_images


ps aux | grep nginx
root      281102  0.0  0.5 195928  6280 ?        Ss   14:52   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data  281103  0.0  1.2 196552 13340 ?        S    14:52   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      281116  0.0  0.1   3452  1576 pts/0    S+   15:00   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx

 ps aux | grep /home/jamelaumn/myproject
root      281104  0.0  2.3  31048 24280 pts/1    S+   14:52   0:00 /home/jamelau                                                                                        mn/myproject/venv/bin/python venv/bin/gunicorn django_project.wsgi --bind 127.0.                                                                                        0.1:8000
root      281105  0.0  4.1  52324 43716 pts/1    S+   14:52   0:00 /home/jamelau                                                                                        mn/myproject/venv/bin/python venv/bin/gunicorn django_project.wsgi --bind 127.0.                                                                                        0.1:8000
root      281193  0.0  0.1   3452  1644 pts/2    S+   15:08   0:00 grep --color=                                                                                        auto /home/jamelaumn/myproject
```

this is the nginx error log:

```
2023/07/10 14:52:12 [info] 281088#281088: Using 131072KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:61
2023/07/10 14:52:26 [info] 281100#281100: Using 131072KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:61
2023/07/10 14:52:40 [error] 281103#281103: *1 open() "/home/jamelaumn/myproject/deploystatic/css/general/normalize.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 189.113>
2023/07/10 14:52:40 [error] 281103#281103: *1 open() "/home/jamelaumn/myproject/deploystatic/css/general/navMenu.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 189.113.2>
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'deploystatic'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

my configuration of /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jamelaumn.com *.jamelaumn.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name jamelaumn.com *.jamelaumn.com;
    ssl_certificate aaaaaaaaaaaaa/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key zzzzzzzzzzzzz/privkey.pem;


    location /static/ {
        alias /home/jamelaumn/myproject/deploystatic;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/jamelaumn/myproject/media;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

my nginx.conf file is with default configuration

(I already collected the static files)

Comment: I went through the same some months ago, don't totally recall how I solved it... Long shot: is the user in nginx.conf "jamelaumn"? Do sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: the user is  www-data;

Comment: please try to recall it i have no idea what might beee

Comment: I kinda fixed it, but it makes no sense, when you talked about the user, i changed to jamelaumn but the service stopped working "root@jamelaumn:~# sudo service nginx restart
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
" so i changed to root and now my staticfiles are being read but I dont get why "jamelaumn" wont work

Comment: First great it now works! It's normal to have to restart the services to apply the new settings. Let's try to make sense of this so we can produce an answer for the next person with the problem: 1) Were you following the "How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 18.04" tutorial from DigitalOcean? 2) In the end, what was the user/user group you have in each file (consider they only apply after restarting)

Comment: I was following the nginx site django tutorial from 2017. The nginx group user and the myproject directory group were the same, and my user "jamelaumn" also has the same group, but the nginx does not accept the "jamelaumn" user only root, or www-data

Answer (score 0):

Your 403 Forbidden issue with Nginx and Django is related to file/folder permissions.

**Nginx oser:**
Ensure the user directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is set to a user with correct permissions. On Ubuntu, it's typically www-data. After making any changes, remember to restart Nginx:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

**Directory permissions:**
All directories leading to your project must be accessible. Make sure that both the directory and its parent directories have the correct permissions. The user group of Nginx (as set in the nginx.conf) and the group ownership of the project directory should ideally be the same for smooth operation.

For instance, if /home/jamelaumn is your project's directory, it should have at least execute permission for the www-data group:

```
chmod g+x /home/jamelaumn
```

In your case, while jamelaumn could be used, there may be other restrictions causing conflicts. Hence, www-data is a more universal and safe choice for Nginx.

Note: avoid root User due to security concerns. Stick to www-data or a similarly limited user.